# create-user "Error: couldn't create User"

Tags: multi-user

I tried creating multiple users on my Android TV dongle (based on RK3188 board). It should work, it's Android 4.4.2, but it returns an error:

```
root@rk3188:/ # pm create-user username
Error: couldn't create User.
```

And at the same time:

```
root@rk3188:/ # getprop fw.max_users
4
root@rk3188:/ # pm get-max-users
Maximum supported users: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should edit your build.prop and add the following lines:

`fw.max_users=2` #in case you want a maximum of 2 users

`fw.show_multiuserui=1` # to show Users menu in settings

Save and reboot. You will then be able to add users

Comment: But according to the question, `fw.max_users` is already more than 2. How will decreasing it solve the problem?

Comment: It is not about decreasing the number of users(the 2 is just an example), but more about modifying his build.prop mainly the fw.show_multiuserui part

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The problem still is as described above from the point of view of CLI. I didn't know about the fw.show_multiuserui settings, this is a nice part, but it still doesn't work, no Users menu is visible in settings after setting it to 1 and rebooting. I suppose the problem is in the way the build has been done and its related to software components that cannot be changed in a compiled image as it's something missing, not just disabled...

Comment: May be my answer should be removed. According to this article [AndroidTV News](https://androidtv.news/2017/05/opinion-android-tv-multi-user-support/), multi-user support isn't available on Android TVs.